# Send email for confirmation during user registration

Tags: email, user-registration, wp-mail

I am very new to WP.How does a confirmation mail is sent during user registration.Is there any services being worked out here. is this a free service using php for any plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress uses by default [`wp_mail()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_mail)<sup>[source](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/pluggable.php#L214)</sup> which is a PHP function very similar to the native PHP [`mail`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php). Hence this *service* is provided by your server/host.

This function is, however, *pluggable*, which means it can be overridden by plugins and custom functions, so it might be slightly different in your case.